# how to convert string value to int value?

Tags: java, android

My code does not show date if day is string not numeric. If I replace the value with a digit like 2,3,4 it works fine, otherwise code throws an error as shown on logcat:

```java
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d is incompatible with java.lang.String
```

This is the code:

```java
String completedate;
String value;
mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

case R.id.e02:

    value = e02.getText().toString();

    completedate = 
        String.format("%02d", value)
        + String.format("%02d", mMonth)
        + mYear;
```

Below is my logcat error

```java
 08-15 11:45:11.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-15 11:45:11.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):    
 java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d is incompatible with java.lang.String
 08-15 11:45:11.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):    at  
 java.util.Formatter$Transformer.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1452)
 08-15 11:45:11.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):    at  
 java.util.Formatter$Transformer.transformFromInteger(Formatter.java:1683)
 08-15 11:45:11.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):    at 
 java.util.Formatter$Transformer.transform(Formatter.java:1410)
 ...
```

Comment: convert the string to integer using parseInt method
int sample = Integer.parseInt(string_value)

Comment: pls for format your code for clarity

Answer (score 4):

Convert by this:

```
int value =Integer.parseInt(string);
```

if String is null then check:

```
if(string.length()>0 || !string.isEmpty()){

  int value =Integer.parseInt(string);

} else{
 // string is Null......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

> Integer.parseInt(string)

Comment: @user2659385 check if the string is null before itself. could you be more specific of what you are doing there might be a better solution

Comment: @user2659385 also use s try catch.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 int value =Integer.parseInt(mystring);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Also use try catch

Throws

NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

So

```
 try{
      int value =Integer.parseInt(mystring);
  }catch(NumberFormatException e) 
  {

  }
```

Not sure what your looking for. As a side note check this

For dates

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Edit:

Assuming you a textview and value is the day

```
       textView.setText(new StringBuilder()
          .append(mMonth ).append("-")
          .append(value).append("-")
          .append(mYear).append(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the string to integer using parseInt method

```
if (e01.getText().toString()== null || e01.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
  // show error message
}
else{ 
   try{
      int sample = Integer.parseInt(e01.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
         //exception
    }
}
```

Comment: check if the code is null the show error message.. see the updated answer

Comment: if i replace mystring with value
value=e01.getText().toString();

Comment: error come   The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type String

Comment: @Amith what if user enters a character instead of a digit. it will throw NumberFormatException . use a try catch block

Comment: The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type String

Comment: error occur The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type String

Comment: e01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e01);