# application force close if string value is null

Tags: android

My code works fine if the string has a value. However, if the string is null, application force close occurs. How do I handle null string value? Help me please.

```
String value;
int value1;
String completedate;
e01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e01);

    case R.id.e01:
        value = e01.getText().toString();
        if (value != null) {
            value1 = Integer.parseInt(value);

            completedate = String.format("%02d", value1) 
                         + String.format("%02d", mMonth) 
                         + mYear;

            Toast.makeText(this, url +completedate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Date not Available", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // string is Null......
         }
         break;
```

Comment: That code is unreadable. You should edit it.

Comment: what does blast mean.? be specific about the problem you are facing

Comment: application force to close

Comment: @user2659385 post the stack trace and pls format your code.

Comment: i paste specific part of my code only

Comment: Hello, please be more specific on your problem, otherwise we can't help. Cheers.

Comment: yes if value is null code is force to close other wise it work perfectly

Comment: if e01.getText().toString();  is null code is force to close other wise run perfectly

Comment: if (e01.getText().toString() != null && !org.apache.common.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(e01.getText().toString())  ?

Comment: org.apache.common cannot be resolved

Comment: Seems like you have to download the .jar from here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: And put it in your /libs folder, then add as external jar in project properties -> java build path -> libraries

Comment: if that's what you're after please let me know so I can post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem.

Let's say your button's text is `""` (no text). When `value = e01.getText().toString();` is called, `value` now has the value of `""` (empty String, NOT null).
Therefore, it satisfies the `if` condition. It then tries to parse `""` as an `Integer`, which will give you a `NumberFormatException` which then force-closes your app.

```
     value=e01.getText().toString();
     if(value!=null){

           value1 =Integer.parseInt(value);
```

If you are certain that the Button's text will be an integer, you simple have to change your if condition to

```
if(!value.equals(""))
```

But if the Button's text might be some non-integer value, use a `try-catch` block instead

```
    try{
        value1 =Integer.parseInt(value);

        // parsed successfully

        completedate=  String.format("%02d", value1) +   String.format("%02d",   
        mMonth)  +mYear;

        Toast.makeText(this, url +completedate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        // value cannot be parsed to an integer

        Toast.makeText(this, "Date not Available", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250272/how-to-convert-string-value-to-int-value/18250320#18250320. i did ask him to put a try catch for his previous question which is related to this question